# String format for $_POST (MultiArrays)

Tags: php, html, http, post

To my knowledge, PHP $_POST is expecting data in the form of 'Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2&(ect..)'. This is the format my application POSTs data to my website. I'm trying to figure out what the format for a multi-dimensional array would be, say 3 dimensions.

Here is what I am thinking:
'MainTable = Table1 = Table1Key1 = Value1 & Table2 = TableKey2 = Value2'

This is my proposed multi-dimension post as a string.

Please help me understand and correct this string!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but `$_POST` is an array. What you reference looks a lot like `$_GET`

Comment: @jboneca — The default data format for POST data in HTML forms is identical to the query string on URLs.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP syntax for form data to be expressed as a multidimensional array is:

```
key[subkey][subsubkey]=1&key[subkey][subsubkey2]=2
```

And then you can access it via:

```
$_POST['key']['subkey']['subsubkey'];
$_POST['key']['subkey']['subsubkey2'];
```

Comment: And they can be dynamic `key[]=1&key[]=2` or `key[subkey][]=1&key[subkey][]=2` etc.

Comment: This answer is the same content as mine, deleting my response!

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question! My new understanding is that my application should post strings in the following format:

MainTable[Table1][Key1InTable1]=SomeValue&MainTable[Table2][Key1InTable2]=SomeValue